# Mobile site repeatedly asks me to join

Tags: bug, mobile

Earlier today I was accessing SE on my iPhone X via the app, and when I tried to access RPG Meta, the app told me I wasn't joined on the site (!?) and asked if I wanted to join.

It did this every time I opened a question to view.

It doesn't do this with the main site.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: I have also been having this problem.

Comment: MSO Dupe: [iOS keeps forgetting that I already joined Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392335/6083675)

Comment: I was this close to taking it there but I thought it only happened on this meta stack. I don’t imagine we can dupe-close across sites, can we?

Comment: @StopBeingEvil: Nope. It's possible to vote to close it for other reasons (or to delete it), but I don't think that's necessary.